# Generalised version of vecnorm - Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, vectorization

I have generalised the function `vecnorm` to calculate the norm along vectors stored in NxNx3 matrices. I would like to make it faster, by vectorising, but haven't been able to do so. Here is my current function

```
function [nr]=VecNorm(r)

N = size(r,1);
nr = zeros(N,N);

for i=1:N
    for j=1:N
        nr(i,j)=norm(reshape(r(i,j,:),[1 3]));
    end
end


end
```

**I/O Example**

```
N=2;   

A = 4.*shiftdim( repmat( eye(3,3), 1, 1, N, N ), 2 );

c = ones(2,2);
V(1,1,:)=[1 2 3];
u = c.*V;
```

> `VecNorm(u)`
>
> ans =
>
> ```
> 3.7417    3.7417
> 3.7417    3.7417
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have at least MATLAB R2017b, then you can use [`vecnorm`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/vecnorm.html) for this:

```
vecnorm(u,2,3);
```

The 3rd argument specifies along which dimension to take the vectors.

If your version of MATLAB is older, you can compute the same with:

```
sqrt(sum(u.^2,3));
```

Again, the `3` argument is the dimension along which to sum.